# Anzai flow in noncommutative geometry

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Consider Anzai flows (cf. Anzai: [Ergodic Skew Product Transformations on the Torus](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200687628), Osaka Math. J. 3 (1951), 83-99) on the two dimensional torus $T^2$. I would like to know if there exists some generalization of the related automorphisms on $C(T^2)$ (the commutative $C^*$-algebras made of all continuous functions on $T^2$) of such homeomorphisms, to the noncommutative 2-torus $A_\theta$.